# How to limit sub array count to 5 for all id values in multi dimensional array php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multi dimensional output array with following structure :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5925
            [fb_id] => 123
            [description] => 
            [video] => 
            [thum] => 
            
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7060
            [fb_id] => 2344
            [description] => 
            [video] => 
            [thum] => 
            
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6579
            [fb_id] => 123
            [description] => 

            [video] => 
            
        )
)
```

Here, I want to limit the sub array count to 5 for all users with same 'fb_id'. Only 5 sub arrays for each fb_id should be in final output array. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Well how are you getting this array? Is it from a MySQL database query? You can use `LIMIT = 5` at the end of your SQL to restrict it to 5 rows.

Comment: I am getting this final array from multiple set of MySQL queries. It's very complex set of queries, and can not use limit for that.

Comment: In theory, I want to traverse the array, get all the sub arrays for all fb_ids and delete the last sub arrays to limit the count to 5 for each fb_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original array being used here is called `$original` and this code will reduce it down and produce a new array called `$new`. Feel free to change the variable names as appropriate.

```
$new = [];
$count = [];
foreach ($original as $element) {
    $fbid = $element['fb_id'];
    if (!isset($count[$fbid])) {
        $count[$fbid] = 0;
    }
    if ($count[$fbid] < 5) {
        $new[] = $element;
        $count[$fbid]++;
    }
}

// New array with limited sub-arrays
print_r($new);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm.